# Chrome Extensions onDeterminingFilename syntax

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have created a simple extension for use on a clients pc to add a save image option to the context menu. Googles Chrome extension documentation, plus examples quoted on the web, leads me to believe I can specify a subdirectory of the 'Downloads' folder as the download target, using 'filename' in the 'onDeterminingFilename' Event.

But I can't figure the syntax. Heres the listener with my pseudo code after 'filename':

```
chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(function(item, suggest) {
suggest({filename: mysubdirectory + item.filename});
});
```

I've tried including mysubdirectory in quotes and with escaped characters, but with no change. The listener works as I've used filename: 'new name' to test it. I'm sure is very very simple,   or maybe I've misunderstood the Event. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

I'd used the wrong quote marks.

This works:

```
chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(function(item, suggest) {
suggest({filename: "mysubdirectory/" + item.filename});
});
```

If mysubdirectory is not present it's created. If it is present, the item is added, plus any other items downloaded. Happy days.

Comment: Next time you're around on this site, consider marking this as answer.